# Возможно ли сделать store и подписку компонентов на него аналогично как в Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, hook

Возможно ли сделать store и подписку компонентов на  него аналогично как в  Redux
чисто на React Hooks ? Возможно есть ссылка на пример ?
или это не есть правильный путь и надо использовать Redux ? что проще ?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно можно, вы просто переносите стейт в ваш костюмный хук.

```
const useCustomStore = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0)
  
  const invrement = () => {
    setNumber(prevState => prevState + 1)
  }

  return { invrement, number } // тут передаем, то что мы хотим использовать в компоненте.
}
```

в компоненте

```
const myComponent = () => {
   const {invrement, number} = useCustomStore() // ВНИМАНИЕ!! это создаст новый экземпляр костюмного стора.
                                                // если вам нужно что бы одно и тоже использовалось в других компонентах, тогда вызовите этот хук на самом высоком родителе и пробрасывайте {invrement, number} контекстом

  return (
     <div>
       <p>{number}<p>
       <button onClick={invrement}> + 1 </button>
     <div>
  )
}
```

Но зачем это все нужно если redux уже сделал это за нас. Хотя все зависит от задач, тут все в вашем желании и голове.

Comment: а нет ли под  рукой  ссылочек на статьи по этому вопросу ?)

Comment: Тут https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/state-management-with-react-hooks-no-redux-or-context-api-8b3035ceecf8 неплохо написано но тут еще глобальный хуки описываться, но мне что-то не прижились. Контекст мне удобней.